# Power BI count number of articles and number of users

Tags: powerbi

I have a table like this
[data & final table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAMo8.png)

How do I calculate number of distinct blog articles and number of users ho visited those articles so I get the table as in the screenshot?

Thanks
Lukas

Answer (score 1):

- You can use table visual in PowerBI and drag the blog articles and
  users column to the visual.
- Click on the down arrow in front of the field in that has been added(in our case **Users**)
- A list of option will open. Click on **Count(Distinct)**
- Do the same thing for **Blog Articles** column.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi Sanchit, but in that case I only got 2 numbers - count of distinct article (=6) and count of distinct users (=4), right? I want to see how many users read 2 articles, how many users read 3 articles, etc

Comment: Ok, then keep the "Users" as don't summarize and keep "Articles" as Distinct in the same table. (Check the second screenshot  - I hope this is what you need)

Comment: Unfortunately, its still not what I need. I have thousands of users so thats is the reason why I want a simple table with the data I described in the  screenshot from original post.